# Multiple svg files overlay

Tags: svgpanzoom

I use JavaScript library https://github.com/ariutta/svg-pan-zoom

Is it possible to add multiple svg files overlay? The zoom function should be done on all the images. The goal is to build a map with dynamic content.

Thanks a lot for your help

Christophe

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in functionality to have multiple overlaid SVGs.

One way to achieve that (probably the easiest) is by using [synchronised SVGs (demo)](http://ariutta.github.io/svg-pan-zoom/demo/sinchronized.html). You'll have to overlay your SVGs using CSS. Then when top SVG fires any pan or zoom events, trigger those on your underneath SVG.

Another way of doing that is to create a compound SVG that would contain all your SVGs or SVGs' contents. Then svg-pan-zoom would work normally with just one SVG (the compound one).